# Array objects to simple object mapping issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to produce the below mentioned object from the array. I have tried map and push from Javascript but I could not achieve it. Please provide some glue to perform this.

```js
fn();

function fn() {
  var env = 'uat';
  var userInput = 'appA';
  var listOfApplications = [
   {
      "appName":"common",
      "data":{
         "uat":{
            "baseUrl":"http://commonurl.com",
            "parameterX":"x",
            "parameterY":"y"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "appName":"appA",
      "data":{
         "uat":{
            "baseUrl":"http://uat.appA.com",
            "parameterA":"a",
            "parameterB":"b"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "appName":"appB",
      "data":{
         "uat":{
            "baseUrl":"http://uat.appB.com",
            "parameterC":"d",
            "parameterD":"c"
         }
      }
   }
];
  var config = {};
  switch (env) {
    case "uat":
        for (const s of listOfApplications) {
            if (userInput == s.appName || 'common' == s.appName) {
                config[s.appName] = s.appName
                config = s.data['uat']
            }
        }
     break;
  }
console.log(config);
return config;
}
```

I am trying to produce the below mentioned output.

```
 {
  "baseUrl": "http://commonurl.com",
  "parameterX": "x",
  "parameterY": "y",
  "appA": {
    "baseUrl": "http://uat.appA.com",
    "parameterA": "a",
    "parameterB": "b"
   }
 }
```

Please help me on this

Comment: Please don't modify your question in a way it invalides given answers. Don't recycle your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

First, I want to explain the problems in your code:

The line

```
config[s.appName] = s.appName
```

sets a property in `config` but the very next line

```
config = s.data['uat']
```

reassigns a new object and overwrites all previous changes. Doing this in a loop results in `config` containing `s.data['uat']` of the last loop iteration where

```
userInput == s.appName || 'common' == s.appName
```

returns `true`. That means `config` either contains the common config or the app config. It also unintentionally modifies your original data. After the first loop iteration, `config = s.data['uat']` sets a reference to an object in your original object. Then, `config = s.data['uat']` adds a property to this object. You can see the problem with a `console.log`:

```js
fn();

function fn() {
  var env = 'uat';
  var userInput = 'appA';
  var listOfApplications = [{"appName": "common","data": {"uat": {"baseUrl": "http://commonurl.com","parameterX": "x","parameterY": "y"}}},{"appName": "appA","data": {"uat": {"baseUrl": "http://uat.appA.com","parameterA": "a","parameterB": "b"}}},{"appName": "appB","data": {"uat": {"baseUrl": "http://uat.appB.com","parameterC": "d","parameterD": "c"}}}];
  var config = {};
  switch (env) {
    case "uat":
      for (const s of listOfApplications) {
        if (userInput == s.appName || 'common' == s.appName) {
          config[s.appName] = s.appName
          config = s.data['uat']
        }
      }
      break;
  }
  console.log(listOfApplications);
  return config;
}
```

The first array element in `listOfApplications` unintentionally got a new property.

**Solution:**

It looks like the expected result is an object containing all properties of the common configuration and a property with app configuration. You can find both configurations using `Array#find`:

```js
fn();

function fn() {
  const env = 'uat';
  const userInput = 'appA';
  const listOfApplications = [{"appName": "common","data": {"uat": {"baseUrl": "http://commonurl.com","parameterX": "x","parameterY": "y"}}},{"appName": "appA","data": {"uat": {"baseUrl": "http://uat.appA.com","parameterA": "a","parameterB": "b"}}},{"appName": "appB","data": {"uat": {"baseUrl": "http://uat.appB.com","parameterC": "d","parameterD": "c"}}}];
  const config = {
    ...listOfApplications.find(({ appName }) => appName === 'common')?.data[env],
    [userInput]: { ...listOfApplications.find(({ appName }) => appName === userInput)?.data[env] }
  };
  console.log(config);
  return config;
}
```

I created a shallow copy of the app configuration to avoid unexpected modifications of the original object. For me complex configurations with nested objects, you should consider a deep copy.

Comment: I agree with u. I have to perform deep copy. One or other reason , I could not use the given snippet and throwing syntax error on online javascript editor. i have updated my code in my question... what is wrong in my deep copy. pls guide me on this

Comment: @Simbu Please don't modify your question to ask follow-up questions. Ask a new question.

Comment: ok @jabaa. accepting your ans

Comment: it is working fine in stackoverflow. But why I am getting below error when I run this code in online javascript editor.. dot is unrecognized in (.data[env],)....  listOfApplications.find(({ appName }) => appName === 'common')?.data[env],
                                                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: @Simbu It looks like the online editor doesn't support modern JavaScript ([optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)) and uses an old engine (>7 years old). Optional chaining is supported since ES6 in 2015.